# В сервисе крутиться цикл

Tags: android

В сервисе крутиться цикл,  я удаляю процесс, Но при обратном запуске приложения. цикл запускает  с нулю обратно,  мне нужно что бы она  крутилось даже когда приложения убилось,  как решить данную проблему

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public MyService() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    if (i % 4 == 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Log.e("my", "i = " + i);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("my", "all = " + i);
                    BusSingleton.getInstance().post(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();


        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) почитайте, так это в таксти и работает

Answer (score 0):

Сервис это часть вашего приложения и его процесса, если вы убиваете процесс - вы убиваете и сервис. Если вы имели в виду что хотите что бы ваш сервис жил когда пользователь работает с другими приложениями, то вам нужно вывести его на передний план методом [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)). При этом вам понадобится так же вывести уведомление в статус бар к которому и прицепится этот сервис.

Comment: есть же приложения такси, там у них реализован таймер. тогда приложения уходит background и удаляешь из background,  и снова запускаешь таймер все еще работает. как они это сделали ? там же  Notification не выходит

Comment: Ну для работы таймера не нужно ничего постоянно крутить в каком то сервисе, надо просто запомнить что и когда должно произойти и запланировать через [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) вызов своего приложения с заданными параметрами в означенное время.